# How to check if Datarow value is null

Tags: c#, datatable, null, datarow

Tell me please is this is correct way to check NULL in DataRow if need to return a `string`

```
 Convert.ToString(row["Int64_id"] ?? "")
```

Or should be like check with DBNull.Value.

Need to so much more smaller than

```
if(row["Int64_id"] != DBNull.Value){...}else if{}
```

Comment: row["ColumnName"] != DBNull.Value, also you can try things like this by yourself. One way is to use debuger !

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Check if the data column is not null with [DataRow.IsNull(string columnName)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?view=net-5.0)

```
if (!row.IsNull("Int64_id"))
{
  // here you can use it safety
   long someValue = (long)row["Int64_id"];
}
```

There are overloads for it using the `index` of the column or if you have the instance of the `DataColumn`. If you are sure about the `index`, use the index version which tends to be faster than the other options.

Comment: returned type `string` and so much smaller

Comment: Checking if the value is the right way to do this. :)

Answer (score 23):

We have created an extension class that helps in these kinds of situations.

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
  {
    public static T FieldOrDefault<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
    {
      return row.IsNull(columnName) ? default(T) : row.Field<T>(columnName);
    }
  }
```

You can use is as follows:

```
int id = dataRow.FieldOrDefault<int>("Id");
```

Comment: How would you put this on the outside of the foreach?