# Input string was not in a correct format - when passing NULL value

Tags: c#, list, null, dataitem

I have the following line of code in my web app.

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtDataItemsSets_1.Rows)
        {
            lst_dataItem_1.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(dr["total"].ToString())); ;
        }
        iData.Add(lst_dataItem_1);
```

If I pass it a decimal it works fine.

However if the value is NULL, I get the following error.

"Input string was not in a correct format"

I understand why this isn't working, but I am not sure how to handle the NULL values?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first thing you'll have to figure out is how you'd like to handle `NULL` values. What should happen in the list?

Comment: I want the NULL value added to the list

Comment: But, as what? It can't be a `Decimal` since `Decimal` does not allow `null` values. You could add it as a `Decimal?`, but whether that works depends on the type of `lst_dataItem_1`.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398037/how-to-check-if-datarow-value-is-null

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that makes sense I cannot store a NULL as a decimal. I have changed the type to string and its working.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of dr["total"] before converting it to decimal:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtDataItemsSets_1.Rows)
    {
        lst_dataItem_1.Add((dr["total"] is null) ? "NULL" : Convert.ToDecimal(dr["total"].ToString())); ;
    }
    iData.Add(lst_dataItem_1);
```